# Adding subpanel - how to run wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

In my new addition I'll be adding a subpanel due to lack of space in existing box.  The issue I've got right now is the walls that I could add a panel in, have a truss directly above the top place, and a floor joist directly below.  Is it code to make some sort of offset on the wall to run the conduit and romex through?

Comment: I don't really follow what you mean.  Are you planning to embed the panel in the wall, or surface mount it?

Comment: It will be embedded in the wall.  It's a finished wall in a bedroom

Comment: Can you provide a diagram of the situation? Also, I take it the walls you want to put the subpanel in run parallel to the trusses/joists?

Comment: Are you talking about the gable end ,everything meets there?  If so you are having a hard time now.Once closed in going to be harder. Can the panel go in other spot?

Comment: If the walls are 2x6 there should be room . And maybe some nail plates ,will be needed. Pics would be helpful.